# Can't show / hide a part in WordPress with the normal loop

Tags: wordpress

I tried the following. When there is content to show, show it + show H3 `<h3>Overview</h3>`, if not show noting.

But this will not work for me.
My code:

```
        <?php 
            $heroimage = get_field('hero_image' ); 
            $alt = $image['title' ];
        ?>
        <?php if ($heroimage) : ?>

            <div class="grid_12">
                <img src="<?php echo $heroimage; ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt; ?>"/>
            </div><!-- End div.grid_12 -->

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <article class="grid_8">
                <h3>Overview</h3>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </article><!-- End article.grid_8 -->

        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

The first part of the Hero image is to get the image from the plugin Advanced Custom Fields. The problem lies on the if have_posts etc..

Thanks for advance!

Comment: I checked your snippet and you have <h3> twice. Are you sure you are not mixing them up? I don't see how <h3>Overview</h3> would show up when you got no posts.

Answer (score 0):

regarding to the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/have_posts), it should be

```
   <?php 
    if (have_posts()) : 
        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <article class="grid_8">
                    <h3>Overview</h3>
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </article><!-- End article.grid_8 -->
       <?php endwhile;
    endif;
    ?>
```

You forgot to close your `if` statement.

Comment: I can't find the problem. I have following your point, but I see the h3 element also when there is no content... Full code of that section: http://snippi.com/s/5ljmlle @Denny Mueller

Comment: nope, tested exactly this snippet... if there are no post at all. the h3 will not be shown. Maybe u mixed up some other h3 elements.